# How to share wishlist email from a custom module in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, module, email, wishlist

I have created a custom module for wishlist, and I need to share email from wishlist which include multiple products in Magento2.2.5?

My Code:

```
<?php
namespace Emipro\GuestWishlist\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;


class Wishlistemailshare extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $scopeConfig;

    protected $_registry;

    protected $request;


    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request, TransportBuilder $transportBuilder)
    {

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        //GetProduct details start
       // print_r($_POST);
    //die('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $messageManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface');
        $cookieManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
        $getProductId = $cookieManager->getCookie('guestwishlistids');
        $product = explode(',', $getProductId);



        $array_product = array();
        $get_product_details = array();

        $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $curruncyFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory');
        $currencyCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $currency = $curruncyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
        $currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
        $cookieId = "";

        foreach ($product as $value) 
        {
            if (!empty($value)) {
        $display_button=1;
        $productId = $value;
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

        // $imageBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
        // $productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($productCollection, 'category_page_list');

        $array_product['image'] = $productCollection->getImage();
        $array_product['product_name'] = $productCollection->getName();
        $array_product['sku_id'] = $productCollection->getSku();
        $array_product['get_urlkey'] = $productCollection->getUrlKey();
        $array_product['product_url']=$productCollection->getProductUrl();
        $array_product['price'] = $productCollection->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($productCollection);

           }
           array_push($get_product_details,$array_product);
        }
        //die;
        //GetProduct details End

        $getPostVal = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        $getFromName = isset($getPostVal["from_name"]) ? $getPostVal["from_name"] : '';
        $getFromEmail = isset($getPostVal["from_email"]) ? $getPostVal["from_email"] : '';
        $getToEmail = isset($getPostVal["email_sep"]) ? $getPostVal["email_sep"] : '';
        $messagee = isset($getPostVal["message"]) ? $getPostVal["message"] : '';

        $to_mail_Array = explode(',', $getToEmail);



        $html = '';

        $test_arr = array("test1", "test2", "test3");

        foreach($test_arr as $val) 
        {
            $html .= "<div class='item'>";
            $html .= "<p> Product Name: ".$val." </p>";
            $html .= "</div>";
        }

        $dfssdf = strip_tags($html);

        $requestData['product_content'] = $dfssdf;


        /* Email send to the shared users - Code Start */
        $requestData['product_details'] = $get_product_details;

        $requestData['mail_subj'] = "Amy Wishlist share";

        $requestData['hello_txt'] = "Hey";

        $requestData['mesg'] = "Take a look at my wishlist from Amy.";

        $requestData['message'] = $messagee;

        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($requestData);

        if(count($to_mail_Array) > 0)  
        {
            foreach($to_mail_Array as $val) 
            {
                if($val != '') 
                {
                    $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                        ->setTemplateIdentifier('wishlist_template')
                        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                        ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                        ->setFrom(['name' => $getFromName,'email' => $getFromEmail])
                        ->addTo($val)
                        ->getTransport();

                    $transport->sendMessage();
                }
            }
        }

        // $val = "ame@gmail.com";

        // $transport = $this->transportBuilder
        //     ->setTemplateIdentifier('wishlist_template')
        //     ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
        //     ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
        //     ->setFrom(['name' => $getFromName,'email' => $getFromEmail])
        //     ->addTo($val)
        //     ->getTransport();

        // $transport->sendMessage();

        /* Email send to the shared users - Code Start */

        $this->_redirect('guestwishlist/index/view');
        return;

        // $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create(); 
        // return  $resultPage;
    } 
}
```

I am just scratching my head from past 4days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve issue?

Comment: No, I have kept on hold. migrating the other modules.